# Creating a compressed archive with "tar" over the network

Tags: tar, archiving

I want to copy a local disk image to another computer in the local network. It is a large directory (around 15 GB) and to speed it up I use this little trick:

```
cd /Volumes/myserver
tar -cvzf image-dir.gz  /Users/francis/image-dir/
```

For the unpacking I can use:

```
cd /
tar -xvzf /Volumes/myserver/image-dir.gz
```

The idea is improve performance by sending only compressed data over the network. However, it's not clear if tar actually does the compression before or after the data has been sent over the network. Does anyone know?

Alternative solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How effective this is depends on where your commands are executed, and where the data is.

Assuming:

1. */Volumes/myserver* is a network share,
2. */Users/francis/image-dir* is on the client's local drive, and
3. both creation and extraction commands are being executed on the *client*,

I think you're correct -- no uncompressed data is crossing the network.

- In the create case, you're reading uncompressed data from the local drive, compressing it, and writing the compressed data to the network drive.  Network transmission is compressed.
- In the extract case, you're reading compressed data from the network drive, uncompressing it, and writing the uncompressed data to the local drive.  Again, network transmission is compressed.

Comment: and this is just analyzing your current process with an eye towards the network data transfer; this is not to say another process won't be more efficient/faster/easier.

Comment: sounds ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen friends pipe `tar` output over `netcat` but I'm at a loss for the syntax. The man pages and a quick web search should be of some help.

Comment: receiver first: `netcat -l -p 7000 | tar x` ... then sender: `tar cf - /Users/francis/image-dir | netcat otherhost 7000`

Comment: caveat: "You'll probably find your hard disk drive is a bottleneck on a fast network. Compression is useless if you can't saturate your network and will probably just slow things down." source: http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/~djw/tarpipe.html

Comment: @quack: I can send data at maximum 12 MB/s over my network. My hard disk is probably much faster than that. Anyway I should time the difference and see for myself..

Comment: @StackedCrooked: that syntax example doesn't do compression over necat; just add the 'z' or 'j' flags to both tar commands for that.